# How to debug my C++ code?

Tags: c++

I get a bad result when I start this code. I want to make a simple calculator, because I'm newbie in C++.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Lithuanian");
    float pasirinkimas, a, b, atsakymas;
    cout << "Pasirinkite veiksmą : ";
    cin >> pasirinkimas;
    if(pasirinkimas = '+') {
      cout << "Ąveskite pirmą skaičių : ";
      cin >> a;
      cout << "Ąveskite antrą skaičių : ";
      cin >> b;
      atsakymas = a + b;
      cout << "Atsakymas yra : " << atsakymas << endl;
      cout << "Ačiū, kad naudojates Neimanto Jociaus kurtu skaičiuotuvu" << endl;
 }
    else if(pasirinkimas = '-') {
      cout << "Ąveskite pirmą skaičių : ";
      cin >> a;
      cout << "Ąveskite antrą skaičių : ";
      cin >> b;
      atsakymas = a - b;
      cout << "Atsakymas yra : " << atsakymas << endl;
      cout << "Ačiū, kad naudojates Neimanto Jociaus kurtu skaičiuotuvu" << endl;
 }
    else if(pasirinkimas = '*') {
      cout << "Ąveskite pirmą skaičių : ";
      cin >> a;
      cout << "Ąveskite antrą skaičių : ";
      cin >> b;
      atsakymas = a * b;
      cout << "Atsakymas yra : " << atsakymas << endl;
      cout << "Ačiū, kad naudojates Neimanto Jociaus kurtu skaičiuotuvu" << endl;
 }
    else if(pasirinkimas = '/') {
      cout << "Ąveskite pirmą skaičių : ";
      cin >> a;
      cout << "Ąveskite antrą skaičių : ";
      cin >> b;
      atsakymas = a / b;
      cout << "Atsakymas yra : " << atsakymas << endl;
      cout << "Ačiū, kad naudojates Neimanto Jociaus kurtu skaičiuotuvu" << endl;
 }
    else {
      cout << "Ąvestas veiksmas neegzistuoja!" << endl;
      exit(0);
 }
    system("PAUSE");
}
```

Comment: what is "a bad result"? what output do you expect? this is what I got: https://ideone.com/7eluVA

Comment: What bad result? What do you expect to happen? And please change the title to something that have to do with your question/problem.

Comment: What do you expect to happen? What is happening instead? What have you tried so far to troubleshoot the problem yourself?

Answer (score 4):

In C++, the operator `=` means assignment. To test for equality, use `==`, e.g.

```
if(pasirinkimas == '+')
```

Otherwise your first `if` will evaluate to `true`, due to the fact that the `char` you assign is converted to non-zero.

Second, your `pasirinkimas` is a `float`, and you attempt to compare with a `char` (actually the read itself will fail if you try inputing a `char` in the line `cin >> pasirinkimas;`, so `pasirinkimas` will remain uninitialized). Use `char` for the type of the former also.

I highly advise you to turn on all compiler warnings. For example, in g++/clang++, you turn them on with `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Weffc++`. They will help you a lot in diagnosing such issues, which otherwise may go unnoticed at first.

Answer (score 0):

Change the type of `pasirinkimas` to char and it should work.